# My JAR file is too big too upload onto AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jar

so i am building an aws project with a lambda function in java i have created the function in INTELLJ as a MAVEN project, and have run the maven package to pakcage my project into a jar file, after i tried directly uploading onto aws lambda but it wouldnt let me because the jar file was too large due to the fact that is was a fat jar, so i tried putting the jar on an s3 bucket and while i was successfully able to put it onto s3 when i tried to refernce from lambda it again gave the size limit error, keeping in mind that my file 65.75 MB and limit was i think 50. So  is there any way i can get around this and still be able to upload the fat 65.75 MB jar onto lambda. Or a way to just cut down the size of the as its kind of a large project.

Any Help Would be Appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot reduce the size: use docker images https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-java

Comment: ok i can try, but aws should still be able to access all the libraries and inline code right?

Comment: You mean in the lambda console? No, that stops working at a few kilobytes of code. And does not work with java at all afaik.

Comment: no, i mean generally like the code itself

Comment: Unclear what you mean. AWS does not "access" or care about the code, it takes your jar or docker container and "runs" it.

Comment: yeah, thats what i meant thanks will try it out

Comment: @ luk2302 - you can certainly upload a JAR using the AWS Management Console. Now the issue here is the size limit.

Comment: @smac2020 i was referring to the inline code editor which is simply not available for Java.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upload your artifact to S3 your code can be up to [250MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) (when it's decompressed)

My advice would be to check your packaging method and follow the instructions on the [Lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html).

If your code needs more than 250MB when it's decompressed then you can use the [container image packaging method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-image.html).

Comment: thank tries this using docker and then puting it on ECR, it works now